# Lambda To Mongodb EC2 instance connectivity Issue

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda

I was trying to add access to the lambda function to connect to the mongodb and have added the subnet CIDR to the “mongodb sg” and did set the outbound of the lambda to access the “mongodb”. That does not seem to work. Have tried clearing the lambda cache with a cold start. Still facing trouble to connect to the mongodb. I have opened up the outbound traffic of the lambda function to the mongodb as well. Not sure why the connectivity is missing here. And the cloud watch logs are very brief that it only states, could not connect to mongodb.

Comment: Are you using MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: yes, I actually found the reason. It was the ssl certificate that was causing issue with login to lambda. I had to include the ssl certificate within the source code used in lambda, for a successful login. Any better way to call the ssl certificate instead of including it in the source code.